# Group only by rows that belong to list

Tags: python, pandas, list, group-by

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'exa', 'tru', 'foo', 'bar', 'exa', 'tru'],
                   'B': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]})
```

Output:

```
     A   B
0  foo  10
1  bar  20
2  exa  30
3  tru  40
4  foo  50
5  bar  60
6  exa  70
7  tru  80
```

And `my_list`:

```
my_list = ['foo', 'bar']
```

I want to perform a `df.groupy('A')['B'].sum()` but only for items in `df['A']` that are in `my_list`.

Comment: kindly post the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using loc

```
(df.loc[df['A'].isin(my_list)]  # rows where A matches my_list
 .groupby('A',as_index=False)['B'].sum()) #groupby and sum
```

```
    A   B
0   bar     80
1   foo     60
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use where for that:

```
df.where(df.A.isin(my_list)).groupby('A')['B'].sum()
```